# What is the order of the following subgroup $\langle (1 \ 2 \ \cdots \ n), (a \ b)\rangle$ of $S_n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer, and consider $H=\langle (1 \ 2 \ \cdots \ n), (a \ b)\rangle\subset S_n.$

It is known that $H=S_n$ if and only if $b-a$ and $n$ are coprime.

**Question.** What is the order of $H$ in general ?

For the moment, I think I have managed to prove the following facts:

Let $d=\gcd(n, b-a)$. Then

- $H$ contains all the transpositions $(k \ k+\frac{n}{d})$

In particular, $H$ contains the subgroup generated by $(1 \ n/d+1 \ 2n/d+1\cdots )$, which is isomorphic to $S_d$, and $d!$ divises the order of $H$.

- $H$ contains all the transpositions $(1 \ 1+ \ell(b-a)),$

and that's pretty much it.

**Thoughts.**

I wonder if $H$ is  isomorphic to a wreath product $S_d\wr S_{n/d}$ or something like that, which would solve the problem.

Of course, if one may show that $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $S_n$, then it would do the trick, since $H$ is transitive and imprimitive if $d>1$.

I woud be extremely surprised if the result was not already known.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is something you could use GAP to gather data for, to see if you find a pattern.

Comment: See exercise 1.21 in Serre's *Finite Groups*. Funnily enough, the exercise talks about a Bourbaki exercise that was wrong, but Serre's exercise is also wrong as well. See if you can figure out the right statement!

Comment: Maybe you could try describing relations between $(12\dots n)$ and $(ab)$ to write $H$ as a presentation.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I have a vague recollection that [Dixon & Mortimer](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0731-3) discusses this. May be as a guided exercise :-)

Comment: @SteveD: which statement of the exercise would be false. The last question about the structure of $G_{r,s}$ ?

Comment: Yes likely a typo: one of the $S$ should be a $C$ (for "cyclic").

Comment: @SteveD You're right : I did few tests, and the right structure should be athe semi direct product of $C_d$ with $d$ copies of $S_{n/d}$ (with my notation. Thanks!