# Structure of the subgroup of $S_n$ generated by a $n$-cycle and a transposition

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

**Context.** This question is a follow-up of [the following one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882537/what-is-the-order-of-the-following-subgroup-langle-1-2-cdots-n-a)

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer, let $d\mid n$, and let $H=\langle\sigma, \tau \rangle\subset S_n,$ where $ \sigma=(1 \ 2 \cdots n), \tau=( 1 \ d+1)$.

According to an exercise of Serre's finite groups, after correction of some typo, one should have $H\simeq (S_{n/d})^d\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$, which is confirmed by a CAS for various values of $n$ and $d$.

For $1\leq k\leq d$, let $E_k=\{ k+m d, m=0,\ldots,\dfrac{n}{d}-1\}$.

One may show that $\sigma(E_k)=E_{k+1}$ and $\tau(E_k)=E_k$ (where the indices are taken modulo $n$). In fact,

Then $H$ acts on $X=\{E_1,\ldots,E_d\}$, and induces a morphism $\rho:H\to S_d$.
The image of $\rho$ is cyclic of order $d$ (generated by $(1 \ 2 \cdots d)$ by the previous considerations, and a permutation acts like the identity if and only if it lies in $S(E_1)\odot\cdots\odot S(E_d)$.

One may show easily that all the transpositions $(i \ i+\ell d)$ lie in $H$, so the kernel of $\rho$ is exactly  $S(E_1)\odot\cdots\odot S(E_d)\simeq (S_{n/d})^d.$

One remains to find is a suitable element $\nu$ of order $d$ in $H$.

Experimentation with a CAS seems to suggest that $\nu=(1 \ 2 \ \cdots d)(d+1 \ d+2 \ \cdots 2d)\cdots ((\frac{n}{d}-1)d+1 \ \cdots n)$ lies in $H$.

I think that this $\nu$ does the job, that is, $H=S(E_1)\odot\cdots\odot S(E_d)\rtimes \langle\nu\rangle$, but I am not able to prove that it lies in $H$ if full generality.

So my question is:

**Question.** How to prove that $\nu=(1 \ 2 \ \cdots d)(d+1 \ d+2 \ \cdots 2d)\cdots ((\frac{n}{d}-1)d+1 \ \cdots n)$ lies in $H$ ?

I will also be happy to have another solution to prove the isomorphism
$H\simeq (S_{n/d})^d\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: I think there's something wrong here. Take $n=4$, $d=2$. Then you are looking at the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,2)$. This contains the transpositions $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, $(3,4)$, and $(1,4)$, which are well known to generate all of $S_4$. But you claim that $\langle (1,2,3,4),(1,2)\rangle\cong (S_2)^2\rtimes C_2$, which has order $8$. Or am I messing up something?

Comment: Do you perhaps need to take $\tau=(1,d+1)$? If we take $\langle (1,2,3,4),(1,3)\rangle$, then this group is not primitive, acting on the blocks $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$, and now it makes more sense that it would be isomorphic to $(S_2)^2\rtimes C_2$. And if we interpret it this way, then $\langle (1,2,3,4),(1,2)\rangle$ corresponds to $d=1$, so you would have $(S_n)^1\rtimes C_1=S_n$, which would also make the previous example correct.

Comment: Yes, this is a typo. I correct it right away

Comment: Do you see what happens when you multiply $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)*(1,d+1)$? What would happen if you did $$(1,2,3,\ldots,n)(1,d+1)(d+1,2d+1)\cdots$$

Comment: @SteveD: Neat! thank you! It was driving me crazy